# I am not getting an Error Correction menu in Visual Studio 2010 Premium

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am currently writing a C# application using Visual Studio 2010 Premium. When using previous versions a menu was shown to correct an error. e.g. "Create Class" or "Change to..."  this menu does not appear.  I now just a Red underline and an error message.  Is there any way top enable the menu?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you were using Resharper or something similar with previous version of visual studio

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I don't think I was using an extension, it was build in.  Of what I remember there was a light bulb in the bar next to the line number to suggest corrections to you.